# Google Maps Geocoding API Usage Limits in android device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, google-api

We are using the Google Maps `Geocoding API` for an application that runs on iOS and Android.We are looking for usage limit for per device and per application.How many time we can call google maps `geocoding api` as per user and application???

Answer (score 0):

There's no quotas per user and applications.

If you Enable the Geocoding API in your Google Developer Console, the standard quota (daily; ends at midnight PST) are

> requests/day  0 of 2,500
>   requests/100seconds/user  Unlimited

The same information can be seen at the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits) page of the documentation. You can also request for additional requests but for a cost.